# Is it possible use _update_by_query in spring elasticsearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

is it possible using Spring Elasticsearch send
 "_update_by_query" [api method](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Update by Query API is not implemented into Spring Data Elasticsearch, but nothing prevents you from using the `TransportClient` you feed into `ElasticsearchTemplate` for [calling that endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-update-by-query.html).